# Why does using the `has` method for a map not give TS enough information to check if value is undefined?

Tags: typescript, dictionary

I am working on some basic practice problems and ran into what I thought should be a fairly trivial problem: using the reducer method to add together values that I have stored in a map.

The issue is, I keep getting an `Object is possibly undefined` error even while attempting to check that case. Is there a better way to check for existance in a map?

```
const resistorColorMap = new Map<string, number>([
  ['black', 0],
  ['brown', 1],
  ...
  ['white', 9],
])

const colors = ['brown', 'white'];

const addColorsValues = (acc: number, cur: string): number => {
  return resistorColorMap.has(cur) ?
    acc + resistorColorMap.get(cur)  // **Object possibly undefined**
    : acc;
}

const sum = colors.reduce(addColorsValues, 0)
```

I get the correct value here, however the TS compiler is still giving me grief about a possibly undefined object in addColorValues.

Comment: TypeScript simply doesn't have information. To TypeScript, `has` *only* returns a boolean, nothing else. There is no type information preserved.

Comment: See [ms/TS#18781](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18781)

Comment: Right, okay that checks out, then my (subjectively) uglier/less-readable workaround would be something like:

`const currentColorValue = resistorColorMap.get(cur) ?? 0;`

I could use the map's `has` in a ternary, but I feel like that complicates things even more. Does this workaround seem like an okay way of going about that?

Comment: Yeah in this case using `??` and a default value seems sensible.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is terse, type-safe and does what's suggested by your problem case.

```js
const resistorColorMap = new Map<string, number>([
  ["black", 0],
  ["brown", 1],
  ["white", 9],
]);

const colors = ["brown", "white"];

const sum = colors.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const digit = resistorColorMap.get(cur);
  return typeof digit === "number" ? acc + digit : acc; 
}, 0);

console.log(sum)
```

You probably didn't intend that actual case as you have to do something about place values. This issue suggests the reducer pattern doesn't make a whole lot of sense here (it rarely does in my experience). Why not use a for...of loop?